# I want to use Java selenium for pull the reports from the website on daily basis. Is it secure?

Tags: java, selenium, security

I want to use java selenium code for automatic login on the website and download reports from that website to my computer. I use an excel sheet for login credential and download reports contain confidential information.

Is it safe to use java selenium? or do I have to do some steps for security purposes?

Comment: if you trust the site, and it uses HTTPS, it's probably secure but I would not use the server, just use Selenium client.  Be aware that if you have malicious code running on your machine, or the machine itself is not secure then all bets are off.  The added attack vectors are vulnerabilities in your running code (getting something from the internet which executes in webdriver's context), or someone attaching to the webdriver's session.

Comment: There is one way in which Selenium is more secure.  It removes it's profile/saved data from the browser when it closes.  (not downloaded files, but cookies, stored logins, auto-suggest stuff, etc...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!         Yes, website is secure . And i am running selenium code from my computer and also reports will download in my computer. There is no server involve in this process.  And please let me know about that secure way which you mention in your last comment. Thank you!

Comment: I just mean it's more secure than manual in that way.  It always removes that session's data.... you don't have to set anything.